# Skip comma on last iteration of loop in Python

Tags: python, string

I am trying to iterate over a dictionary in Python. The output has to resemble a certain format so it can be used as input for something else. The input looks like this:

```
"ok":"1",
"invalid", "0",
"unknown", "4",
...
```

The output should look like this:

```
operation,ok=1,invalid=0,unknown=4,...
```

I am really close to getting it with a for loop but I read that this can be done very easily with `.join()` in Python. Here is my code right now:

```
output_str = 'operation,'
for key, val in events.items():
    output_str += '{0}={1},'.format(key, val)
print output_str
```

Can I do this using `.join`? I read that join will allow me to skip the comma on the last iteration. I'm just not sure how to prepend my "operation," string to it all if I do it this way.

Comment: Simply use `output_str += ','.join('{0}={1}'.format(key,val) for key,val in events.items())` to replace the **entire** `for` loop...

Comment: You dropped a ` there, Willem! edit: ok, it's up now! I think your comment is a fitting answer and so you should post it as one.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you should write as answer with a short explanation. this is exactly what the OP asked for and needs

Comment: Yes, thank you @WillemVanOnsem. That worked perfectly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can indeed use a `str.join` function here to join the different elements together:

```
output_str = 'operation,'
output_str += ','.join('{0}={1}'.format(key,val) for key,val in events.items())
```

Or putting it in a *one-liner* (and even make it shorter):

```
output_str = 'operation,'+','.join('{0}={1}'.format(*tup) for tup in events.items())
```

**How does this work?** As is specified in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.join#str.join), `str.join` takes an `iterable` of `str`ings and joins them together with the separator (here `','`). So `','.join(['foo','bar','qux'])` generates `'foo,bar,qux'`.

Now here we use a *generator*. For `key,value` pair in `events.items()`, we *construct a string* with `'{0}={1}'.format(key,val)`. So if `key='ok'` and `val='1'`, then `{0}={1}'.format(key,val)` will generate `ok=1`. Now we join all these together.

Since `str.join` does **not add a tailing separator**, thus it meets the specifications of your question. `join` will usually also outperform string concatenation (in a loop).

Answer (score 1):

the function you are looking for is `str.rstrip()`
it takes a list of characters to remove so you can do

```
output_str = output_str.rstrip(',')
```

but the solution suggested by Willem Van Onsem is better, as it avoids the issue to begin with.